# rsync is changing my directory permissions

Tags: rsync

I have an rsync setup that transfers files from my local development machine to my production web server. On the production server, the `storage` directory needs to be 775.

When the rsync completes, it gets changed to 755

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man rsync`:

```
-p, --perms                 preserve permissions
```

Assuming that you want to preserve all metadata and not just permissions, you probably want to use `-a` with `-HAX`, which implies `-p`.

```
-a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
```

Answer (score 14):

I add this answer since the accepted one doesn't do the required stuff for me (using -p does not prevent rsync to change perms on destination path)!

Indeed, the appropriate option here (for NOT changing perms of existing stuff) is `--no-perms`

```
rsync --no-perms src/ /dest
```

Hereafter extract from the `rsync` man:

> In summary: to give destination files (both old and new) the source
>   permissions, use --perms. To give new files the destination-default
>   permissions (while leaving existing files unchanged), make sure that
>   the --perms option is off and use --chmod=ugo=rwX (which ensures that
>   all non-masked bits get enabled).

Comment: `--no-perms` is the default already, it shouldn't be necessary in this example.

Comment: @sourcejedi as far as I understand it `rsync` try to reproduce _by default_ the same permission from the source to the dest, so the option `--no-perms` is not the default!

Comment: If permission bits are turned off in the source file, rsync will apply the same to the destination file, `--no-perms` is the default and adding it does not change behavior.  The man page does suggest adding `--chmod=ugo=rwX` if you want to re-enable the permission bits in the destination file, so I think _that's_ the option you need.  Ownership (including group) is not copied by default, it's just the permission bits.

Comment: I was having a similar problem to the original question. Adding the --no-perms option seemed to work for me, without having to add the --chmod option.