# rsync - how to leave destination folder unaffected by permission settings

Tags: permissions, rsync

I want to mirror everything in source_folder to dest_folder and change the permissions of the files and folders being transfered to user and group. However the permissions of dest_folder are also changing. Is there a way to make dest_folder unaffected of the permissions that are being set by rsync?

`rsync -trvzXEsog --chown=owner:group --chmod=750 /source/source_folder/ /dest/dest_folder/`

I have googled plenty but I can only find topics discussing how to set permissions for all files and folders being transfered, such as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65621/rsync-is-changing-my-directory-permissions) one.

Comment: 1) `-og` seems uncompatible with `--chown=owner:group` 2) `--chmod=750` will change permission can't you simply drop that command ?

Comment: Hmm, if I remove -og then --chown=owner:group has no effect. Regarding removing --chmod=750, I want to set new user and owner and permissions for the files and folders being transferred but not for the destination folder, which I thought would be left unchanged.